# Database design problem: where to put UNIQUE constraint

Tags: database-design, unique-constraint

I have the following three tables:

```
Form
-----------
formId INTEGER       PK
name   NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL

Block
-----------
blockId     INTEGER        PK
name        NVARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL
orderInForm INTEGER        NOT NULL

FormBlock
-----------
blockId  INTEGER  PK
formId   INTEGER  PK
```

There is a many-to-many relationship. A block could appear on multiples forms. `orderInForm` is for a particular form.

On `Block` table I want to avoid that two blocks have the same `orderInForm` in a `Form`.

I think I have to add an UNIQUE constraint, but if `orderInForm` is on `Block` table, I don't know how to do it.

May I need to move `orderInForm` to `FormBlock` table?

Comment: Is there really a many-to-may relationship between forms and blocks?  One block can appear on multiple forms?  If there is a many-to-many relationship, should the `orderInForm` be for a particular form?  Or should it apply to all forms?

Comment: There is a many-to-many relationship. A block could appear on multiples forms. `orderInForm` is for a particular form. I will add this to my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `orderInForm` is the position of a particular block on a particular form, it should be a column in the `FormBlock` table, not a column in the `Block` table.  If `orderInForm` is in the `Block` table, a block would need to have the same position in every form it was on.

Once you move the column to `FormBlock`, you can then create a unique constraint on the combination of `(form_id,orderInForm)` on the `FormBlock` table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand one thing: you say that a unique constraint on the combination of (blockId, orderInForm), but I think that unique constraint must use three FormBlock's columns. Why do you use only two? I can use the same block in the same position with two or more forms.

Comment: @VansFannel: I think you are (partially) right, the unique constraint should be on table `FormBlock` but in the `(formId, orderInForm)` combination.

Comment: @ypercube - Yes, that was my mistake.  Fixed my answer.